# Transparently proxifying certain devices on the network

Tags: linux, routing, iptables, squid, transparentproxy

I'm using my computer as wireless access point and router to my home network using hostapd under Ubuntu 14.04. I want to transparently proxify certain wifi devices in the network (identified by their MAC addresses). How do you propose I go about doing that? I think a combination of squid and iptables should do the trick, but I don't have more than a cursory knowledge of these.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this myself:

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -m mac --mac-source "MAC-ADDRESS" -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 33128
```

Squid is running on port 33128. I had to write this in squid.conf so that transparent proxy-ing works correctly:

```
http_port 33128 transparent
```